# prevent $_POST bombing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a contact form that sends to my email and I recently got attacked by some sort of spam attack... I received like 76k emails overnight from the same IP address.  It made me really mad.  What can I do to fix this? I know I can implement captcha but I don't want that. :\

What else can I do to prevent multiple form submit?

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` to save the last time a contact form was submitted and the number of submissions during this session. When the count is above 3 and last time is lower than 5 minutes ago, post a warning and update last time to prevent spams.

Comment: @Khez that only works if the client handles cookies. If not then a new session will be created for each request. I don't think this is spammer proof.

Comment: @James true, that's why I only commented and not answered. Was just trying to nudge him in the right direction.

Comment: To know more about how to avoid spam, consider browsing questions on webmasters.stackexchange.com - there is a lot of information on the topic there!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to stop this in a number of different ways:

- CAPTCHA (you already said you didn't like it but it's possibly the easiest solution)
- Answering some kind of question that it's easy for a person to answer but not a script
- Making sure the user is signed in before they can submit (assuming they have to be registered)
- Rate limit the form so that each IP address can only submit once every N period of time

Comment: I prefer a combination of session and IP address. But +1 for offering multiple solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), which does not use validation.

Comment: Very nice solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid captcha, you can filter IP, for example allow maximum 10 messages per day from the same IP.

Every time someone send a message store the ip and increment a counter in a database.

Answer (score 0):

a captcha is a very common way to prevent such (and for a very good reason, you should think about it)

if not you could set a cookie and check whether its set, if it is, disallow sending the mail, or log the ip in a file or a database and check when the ip last sent the mail, and if the difference is small enough, disallow the mail to be sent

Comment: -1 He just said he knows he can implement captcha, but doesn't want it. This was better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The single easiest thing to do is to make the form submission (or rendering) require javascript execution. It's a little antisocial for anyone who has NoScript installed, but the majority of automated scripts won't be able to handle it.

Comment: Kind of a false answer. Automated scripts send POST requests directly to the page. JS won't do anything to help with his bombing.

Comment: If the only way to get a valid POST URL is to execute some JS, then it works.

Comment: You imply that the post URL changes with each refresh, that's horribly ugly. You add overhead to a solution that your legit users might not even be able to user.

Comment: There isn't an elegant way out of this. Any solution is going to involve ugliness of some sort.

Comment: Hurting your legit users and your resources is uglier than needed.

Comment: Is there an approach which *doesn't* do this?  Captcha does, rate limiting does, having the user answer a question does - of all the suggestions I've seen, akismet is the lowest impact and that *still* needs resources (and possibly development time, unless you're on a platform with an available plugin). Simply requiring JS execution is something that most legit users will never even realise is in place.